# Einreicher oder Einreichender?

Tags: word-choice

Ich suche den korrekten Begriff für die "einreichende Person". Leider kennen weder der Duden, noch meine schlauen Bücher die o.a. Begriffe.

Es könnte die "einreichende Partei oder Person" sein, dann wäre dieser Begriff auch als 'Die Einreichende' abzukürzen, aber nicht als "Der Einreichende", es könnte aber auch ein Fachbegriff sein, der es nicht in den Duden geschafft hat.

Ansonsten bin ich geneigt, die Parallele zu dem Wort "schreiben" zu ziehen, bei dem die Rede vom "Schreiber" ist, aber beim "reisen" ist es umgekehrt, da wird vom "Reisenden" gesprochen.

Ich brauche neben der Erklärung auch eine zuverlässige Quelle.

Comment: Meiner Meinung nach ist der interessante Aspekt, dass "einreichend" ein Partizip Präsens ist. Es gilt also nur, während derjenige einreicht. (Ein Reisender, der angekommen ist, ist auch kein Reisender mehr, sondern ein Gereister.)

Comment: Ich stimme guidot zu, der Einreichende ist derjenige der jetzt gerade, oder aber in der Zukunft, etwas einreicht. Der Einreicher ist allgemein derjenige, der etwas einreicht.

Comment: @guidot: Wird das wirklich so verwendet? Ein "Vielreisender" zum Beispiel  ist für mich jemand der generell viel reist. Ob dieser gerade jetzt unterwegs ist, wäre für mich unerheblich.

Comment: Gut, dann würde ich das gerne noch etwas weiterführen: Wenn der Reisende nach der Ankunft nicht den Status des Reiser, sondern des Gereisten hat und der Schreiber zum Schreibenden werden kann, aber nicht zum Geschriebenen, können der Einreicher - so es ihn im Deutschen gibt - und der Einreichende - so es ihn im Deutschen gibt - zum Beispiel eines Antrages unterschiedliche Personen sein? Oder hat der Einreichende ( Bote ) den Status des Einreichers, wenn der Antrag sein Ziel erreicht hat, obwohl der Einreicher doch eigentlich der Antragsteller sein sollte?

Comment: Mir kommt bei der Gelegenheit auch der Einbrecher und der Einbrechende in den Sinn.

Comment: Ich bin auch bei @guidot und werfe mal den "Antragsteller" vs. "Antragstellenden" aus dem Bürokratendeutsch in den Raum. Antragssteller kann man auch noch Jahre nach dem eigentlichen Antrag sein, Antragsstellender nur in dem Augenblick, wo man vor dem Schalter steht. Zum "Vielreisenden": Das ist ja einer, der "immer reist". Also annähernd auch "grade jetzt". Reist er nicht mehr, ist's ein "Vielgereister".

Comment: Vielleicht brauchen wir noch einen Hinweis, was denn da eingereicht wird.

Comment: Grob gesagt: Wir sind in der IT und die Person, die eintippt ist eine andere als die, die es betrifft und die den Inhalt liefert. Etwas genauer: Das Interface, das einen Code überträgt soll die einreichende Instanz ( Person wäre falsch ) sein und der Prozess, der den Inhalt liefert, ist der Einreicher. Beides keine Personen und trotzdem müssen die Eigenschaften klar definiert und die Vorgänge sauber dokumentiert sein.

Comment: Da gibt's in der IT aber eindeutig bessere Begriffe, wie Aktor, Klient oder Prozessinitiator, Datenlieferant, Requestor.... Sowohl "Einreicher" als auch "Einreichender" würde mindestens eine Augenbraue von mir bekommen.

Comment: Das werde ich definitiv für meine Doku in Betracht ziehen, vielen Dank. Trotzdem interessiert mich jetzt, ob es eine Quelle gibt, die das Problem klärt. :c)

Comment: @user31522 Du solltest die Frage editieren und den IT-Kontext dort erläutern. In den Kommentaren könnte er überlesen, bzw. gelöscht werden.

Comment: Gleiche Frage wie: »Student« oder »Studierender«

Comment: @HubertSchölnast "Studierer" oder "Studierender", wenn schon. "studens", woher der Student kommt, ist genauso wie "Studierender" Partizip Präsens.

Answer (score 2):

Ein *Einreicher* ist grammatisch die Substantivierung des Verbs "einreichen", also ganz einfach jemand, der etwas einreicht, gerade einreicht, oder eingereicht hat.

Ein *Einreichender* ist grammatisch die Substantivierung des Partizip I des Verbs "einreichen". Das Partizip I hat auch den schönen deutschen Namen "Ablaufform des Verbs", das wiedergibt, dass man mit dem Partizip I die *gerade laufende  Tätigkeit* ausdrücken kann, also eine Art Verlaufsform. Damit ist ein *Einreichender* nur solange "jemand, der einreicht", solange diese Tätigkeit noch anhält. Sobald der akute Vorgang abgeschlossen ist (also auch z.B. solange das, was auch immer eingereicht worden ist, bearbeitet wird) kann man den *Einreicher* deshalb nicht mehr als *Einreichenden* bezeichnen.

Nehmen wir als Beispiel ein paar mögliche Substantivierungen von deinem Beispiel *reisen*:

- **Reiser** - jemand der reist, in seiner puren Form sehr ungebräuchlich, aber z.B. als "Vielreiser" (Vielflieger) bisweilen gebraucht.
- **Reisender** - jemand der gerade reist oder "für gewöhnlich reist".
- **Gereister** - jemand der früher viel gereist ist. Ebenfalls in dieser Form ungebräuchlich, findet sich aber z.B. im "Weitgereisten* wieder.

Answer (score 0):

Sender ist in der IT gebräuchlich.

Zwischen *Sender* und *Sendendem* zu unterscheiden (erster wäre die Quelle, der zweite der Vermittler) ist schwierig, wenn die Daten nicht so lange gepuffert werden, dass der Sender schon inaktiv ist, bevor der Sendende angefangen hat. Sprachlich ergibt sich dann keine eindeutige Zuordnung.

Auch für die Beschreibung vergangener Vorgänge ist es unpraktisch, eine Instanz *Sendender* nennen zu wollen oder äquivalente Bildungen mit anderem Wortstamm vorzunehmen. Man müsste *der damals Sendende* oder ähnliches benutzen, um ihn von der Quelle zu abzugrenzen. Die Begrifflichkeit bleibt zwar so oder so missverständlich, solange man nicht mindestens beide Begriffe nebeneinander sieht, aber wenigstens muss man keine Sprachgymnastik betreiben.

Die übermittelnde Instanz kann man Übermittler nennen. (auch möglich: Transporteur, Vermittler, Medium, Provider). Für den Sender ist auch Quelle denkbar.

Comment: Den ersten Satz im zweiten Absatz willst du nochmal überarbeiten.